# deploy projects folder parallely into tomcat and local repo

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Is that possible to deploy a project to maven local repository and tomcat at the same time?

currently, I'm using this approach to deploying my app to tomcat.but I need to deploy this to the local repo(`mvn install`) same time as well.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/myapp</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I do this configuration via eclipse or command line?

```
Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ spring-rest ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [spring-rest] in [/home/trever/workspace/spring-rest/target/spring-rest]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/trever/workspace/spring-rest/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [842 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/trever/workspace/spring-rest/target/spring-rest.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ spring-rest <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ spring-rest ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/spring-rest  
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fspring-rest
Uploaded: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fspring-rest (14407 KB at 100748.0 KB/sec)

[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
[INFO] OK - Deployed application at context path /spring-rest
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.269s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 17 19:29:03 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/201M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Before deploying to tomcat it schould do a build which already installs the war to local repository... Did you check your local repo?

Comment: yes.. it's not going to local repo

Comment: Can you provide the output of your deploy command..

Comment: I run this command 'mvn tomcat7:deploy'

Comment: what about this command? mvn clean install tomcat7:deploy

Comment: Something like `mvn install tomcat7:deploy` should work,

Comment: ya this command works fine.anyway is this fine to do again and again or are there any better ways to accomplish this..thanks guys

Comment: Define "better". For me something that works as documented is good enough, so what do you mean with "better" ? You might not use Maven directly but deploy from an IDE for development purposes, perhaps that works "better" for you. I tend to let Maven create a build for me when I want to deploy outside my development environment.